# Emberjs Model from route returning undefined in controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-octane

I have a strange behavior with my Ember app. I can't make any sense out of it.
Basically I'm using Ember octane and I wanted to access my model from my `route` to my `controller` .

This is my route

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default class ChatIndexRoute extends Route {
  model() {
    return {
      chatMessages: [
        {
          username: '1',
          message: 'Hi',
          read: true,
        },
        {
          username: '1',
          message: 'how are you?',
          read: false,
        },
        {
          username: '1',
          message: 'its been a long time :)',
          read: false,
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model.chatMessages);
  }
}
```

and this is my controller

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';


export default class ChatIndexController extends Controller {
  init() {
    super.init(...arguments);
    console.log('test', this.model);
  }
}
```

When I `console.log(this.model)`
I got `undefined`.

**But** when I simply do a `console.log(this)`
I got a whole object with a model property filled with `chatmessages`

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx8oD.png)

This is crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a little timing confusion. `init()` on the controller is executed *before* `setupController` on the route. so `this.model` is `undefined`.

But when you do `console.log(this)` you get the complete controller logged. And the magic of the console is that it is live. So when this object later (not much later, just a tiny little bit) will be updated, you will see it in the console. And so you can inspect the `model` property on the controller in the console, even if it wasnt there when you logged the controller.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for this would be using the model directly in template, and another work around is using computed properties.

```
export default class ChatIndexController extends Controller {
  init() {
    super.init(...arguments);
    console.log('test', this.model);
  }
  chatMessages: computed(function(){
     console.log(this.model); //will print the model
  }
}
```